# Certutil.exe error exit code when running with elevated Start-Process

Tags: powershell, certutil

I'm trying to import a certificate with `certutil.exe` with a script. This script is launched with a non-admin user, and when reaching `Start-Process` command, windows UAC asks for admin credentials.

```
$cmd="certutil.exe -addstore TrustedPeople C:\some_path\myCertif.cer"
$ret = Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $cmd -Wait -PassThru
```

`$ret.exitCode` is equal to 1 when I run this code, and no certificate can be found in the store.

However if I run Start-Process without `-ArgumentList` (a powershell windows open then), and run the `certutil.exe` command from here , I got no error and the certificate is added to the store as expected.

Where is the difference ?

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you make an error: you invoke a new instance of PowerShell and pass `$cmd` string which does not represent valid input for Powershell.

You invoke:

`powershell.exe certutil.exe -addstore TrustedPeople C:\some_path\myCertif.cer`

while PowerShell expects input like this:

`powershell.exe .\somescript.ps1`

`powershell.exe -Command 'some_command'`

`powershell.exe -EncodedCommand 'base64_command'`

... and so on ...

In the second case you just start a new elevated instance of PowerShell, which then lets you successfully import a certificate.

To import a certificate from PowerShell, I'd suggest three solutions based on your example:

1) use `certutil.exe` directly:

```
$arguments = '-addstore TrustedPeople C:\some_path\myCertif.cer'
$ret = Start-Process 'certutil.exe' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -PassThru
```

2) if for some reason (just in case) you want to invoke another PowerShell instance, you can use `Command` option like this:

```
$cmd = 'certutil.exe -addstore TrustedPeople C:\some_path\myCertif.cer'
$ret = Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-Command $cmd" -Wait -PassThru
```

3) and finally for the sake of completeness, you can use `EncodedCommand`:

```
$cmd = 'certutil.exe -addstore TrustedPeople C:\some_path\myCertif.cer'
$bytes = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($cmd)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$ret = Start-Process 'powershell.exe' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "-EncodedCommand $encodedCommand" -Wait -PassThru
```

Also in my testing environment (Windows 7 Enterprise x64 with PowerShell v.2) I failed to actually get `certutil.exe` return code using `Start-Process` cmdlet when running my script with non-elevated privileges. I used .Net functions to solve this problem:

```
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$pinfo.FileName = 'certutil.exe'
$pinfo.UseShellExecute = $true
$pinfo.Verb = 'runas'
$pinfo.Arguments = '-addstore TrustedPeople C:\some_path\myCertif.cer'

$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo
$p.Start() | Out-Null
$p.WaitForExit()
Write-Host $p.ExitCode
```

I hope that's what you need!